# How to get links from html using regex

Tags: html, regex

Some content was spammed with external links
How do you select both url tag and text in regex

example

```
This is a legit content. It was Created by the admin
```

After Spam

```
This is a legit <a href="http://www.fakesite.com">Buy shoes</a> content. It was Created by <a href="http://www.veryfakesite.com">Buy Really nice shoes </a> the admin
```

in this case i want to highlight and wipe it so the original content remains

```
This is a legit content. It was Created by the admin
```

Comment: You should tell us which tool/language you are using, or perhaps you don't even know what you should be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the regex engine/tool you are using, the following find and replacement should work:

**Find:**

```
\s*<a href[^>]*>.*?</a>\s*
```

**Replace:**

```
(a single space)
```

This should get you fairly close to what you want.  In addition to matching each anchor spam tag, I also pull in all whitespace on either side, and then replace the entire pattern match with just a single space.

### Demo